# Copy file path to other variable in multer

Tags: node.js

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname+ '-' + Date.now()+'.jpg')
    }
});
var upload = multer({ storage:   storage });

app.post('/multer', upload.single('file'));
```

I want that after hitting the api path of file or we can say file name written in above code should be show in console.log

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
           cb(null, './uploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    var fileName = file.originalname+ '-' + Date.now()+'.jpg';
    console.log(fileName);
    cb(null, fileName);
    }
   });
var upload = multer({ storage:   storage });

app.post('/multer', upload.single('file'));
```

**EDIT**: For the info to be used later on, the best way is to add an additional middleware to app.post, for example:

```
app.post('/multer', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); // form fields
    /* example output:
    { title: 'abc' }
     */
    console.log(req.file); // form files
    /* example output:
            { fieldname: 'upl',
              originalname: 'grumpy.png',
              encoding: '7bit',
              mimetype: 'image/png',
              destination: './uploads/',
              filename: '436ec561793aa4dc475a88e84776b1b9',
              path: 'uploads/436ec561793aa4dc475a88e84776b1b9',
              size: 277056 }
     */
    res.status(204).end();
});
```

Replace `console.log(req.file);` with your mongodb call.

Comment: and can I send file path to mongo database...plz how to do this

Comment: Edited answer with your requirement

Comment: Upload.single('file') and function(req,res){}. ....when one is working then other is not workin And not running simultaneously... I think callback is requires but dnt know how